# Get `\tau` from libertine font

Tags: fonts, symbols, newtxmath, extract

Extracting a single symbol from a certain font looks really sophisticated and it seems like each font is needed its own approach.

Now I would like to extract the single `\tau` from `\usepackage{libertine} \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`, it looks perfect for me.

[image]

Here is the setup I have just to prevent any conflicts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{polynom}

\usepackage{xparse}

% --- get \lwavy --- %
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE5
    <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
    <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
    <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
    <9-10> MnSymbolE9
    <10-12> MnSymbolE10
    <12->   MnSymbolE12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
    <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
    <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
    <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
    <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
    <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
    <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mnlargesymbols}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{mnlargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lwavy}{\mathopen}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rwavy}{\mathclose}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}


% --- Get fancy 'u' and 'v' --- %
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathtx}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{mathtx}{117}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{mathtx}{118}

\begin{document}

\[
\tau : \enspace \frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{9}-\frac{z^2}{100}=-1
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If it is your intention to load a new package for every symbol (cf. your previous question on changing the fonts for u and v), note that Latex may object if there are too many fonts used at once. This includes not only fonts which you load here, but also additional fonts which might be loaded with a journal's class file if you submit for publication.

Comment: Your document will be like a ransom letter.

Comment: I was always wondering if there is a document class option `\documentclass[ransom]{letter}`. There seems to be high demand. ;-)

Comment: @egreg xD Nice one! I can agree that 'u' and 'v' might stand out among others, but this tau looks good.

Comment: @antshar I heartily disagree! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the relevant lines to your code. The output is now with the correct `\tau`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{polynom}

\usepackage{xparse}

% --- get \lwavy --- %
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE5
    <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
    <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
    <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
    <9-10> MnSymbolE9
    <10-12> MnSymbolE10
    <12->   MnSymbolE12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
    <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
    <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
    <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
    <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
    <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
    <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mnlargesymbols}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{mnlargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lwavy}{\mathopen}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rwavy}{\mathclose}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}

% --- Get fancy 'u' and 'v' --- %
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathtx}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{mathtx}{117}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{mathtx}{118}

% --- Get 'tau' from libertine --- %
\makeatletter
\newif\iflibus@sansmath
\makeatother
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{libertinust1math}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{LettersLibertinus}{LS1}{libertinust1math}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathord}{LettersLibertinus}{"1C}


\begin{document}

\[
\tau : \enspace \frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{9}-\frac{z^2}{100}=-1
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you tell how you came up with the solution?

Comment: It should be `\mathord`: you don't want that `\tau` is influenced by the current math group.

Comment: @egreg Thank you, I edited my answer.

Comment: @antshar In my experience, to find this kind of information, it's often instructive to look in the files of the package that loads the font. In this case, that's probably what I did but I'm not sure (when I read your question, I just remembered that I had done something similar with this font, so I wrote my answer from my old code).

Answer (score 0):

In the modern toolchain with `unicode-math`, you could do this with `\setmathfont`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[mathit=sym]{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0] % Corresponding to newtxtext
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math} % Corresponding to newtxmath
\setmathfont[range=\mittau]{Libertinus Math} % Or range=it/{Greek,greek} for all Greek letters

\begin{document}
\[
\tau : \enskip \frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{9}-\frac{z^2}{100}= -1
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus/Termes sample]

The `mathit=sym` option uses the patched symbols by default, without having to write `\symit\tau` or `\symnormal\tau`.  If you want to be able to use other alphabets the same way, you would need to add `mathrm=sym`, `mathbf=sym`, etc.

The macro `\mittau` comes from [“Symbols Defined by unicode-math”](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf).  The naming schema is regular, though: upright Θ is `\mupTheta`, bold **θ** is `\mbftheta`, bold italic ***α*** is `\mbfitalpha`.